# Call java applet method from JavaScript = is not a function

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have defined the following Java Applet:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CombineData extends Applet{

    private File destinationFile;
    private FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;


    public boolean setUpFile(String filePath) {

        // This is just to check if it is a new file we write to or not
        // We could return false at once saying file already exists
        boolean result;
        if ((destinationFile = new File(filePath)).exists()) {
            result = false;
        } else {
            result = true;
        }

        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile, true);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public boolean write_line(byte[] data) {
        if (fileOutputStream == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            try {
                fileOutputStream.write(data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void finished() {
        try {
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the following JavaScript

```
function start_button() {
    combineDataApplet = document.getElementById('combineDataApplet');
    combineDataApplet.setUpFile("blabl");
    var filename = "~/Downloads/" + prompt("Please enter file name (remember file extenstion)", "combined_data.txt");
    console.log(filename);
}
```

And finally the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <script src="js/page.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div>
      <applet id="combineDataApplet" code="CombineData.class" width="350" height="350">
        APPLET
      </applet>
      <input id="start_button" type="button" onClick="start_button()" value="start"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I get the following error: `TypeError: combineDataApplet.setUpFile is not a function. (In 'combineDataApplet.setUpFile("blabl")', 'combineDataApplet.setUpFile' is undefined)`

I have found a few post on stackoverflow which states that I need to put it into a div block without a `display:none` but there are no styles on any of my divs and by such there should be no `display:none`.

I hope someone can help me figure out what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Programming Applets is riding a dead horse.

*untested*: you should access the applet this way:

```
document.combineDataApplet.setUpFile("blabl");
```

and not by `document.getElementById()`. The latter only gets you the DOM element containing the applet.

**Edit:**

here is a link from January 2016 about [Oracle deprecating Applets](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/01/oracle-deprecates-the-java-browser-plugin-prepares-for-its-demise/). This article gives the further link to Oracle's [whitepaper for migrating applets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/migratingfromapplets-2872444.pdf). I haven't read it, but it might show you some alternatives.

Comment: What would you use instead of applets ?

Comment: oh and I know - my problem is that I need more memory than JS has available

Comment: a backend service for example with a REST interface and a JS frontend for the UI. The NSPlugin interface that Applets rely on is deprecated if not already removed from modern browsers, so when depending on Applets you force the users to use outdated browsers.

Comment: Backend Service is not an option

Comment: I added some links to my answer

Comment: Thanks, though this kills my idea completely

Comment: Then what exactly is `document.combineDataApplet`, if not an `HTMLElement`?